# Animating GMSMapView

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I tried all the animation methods provided by google maps. But I fail to animate the zoomlevel of map view. I have tried mapView.animateToZoom(15). Also

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(5.0, animations: {
                    let zoomIn = GMSCameraUpdate.zoomTo(15)
                    self.mapView.animateToZoom(15)
                })
```

But I fail to achieve the animation. I also followed [GMSMapView animateToCameraPosition zoom in - zoom out animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30898937/gmsmapview-animatetocameraposition-zoom-in-zoom-out-animation)

But no hope. Can anyone help please?

Comment: I guess it is because `GMSMapView` is not consist of UIKit. Anyway, `animateToZoom` is already a animation. Why do you need it in `UIView`'s animation block?

Comment: I was just trying by using it in UIView's animation block! Simply using 
                    self.mapView.animateToZoom(15) doesnot animate the map View

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a lot of struggle I managed to animate the GMSMapView: Here is the code for the reference:

```
mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(58.998400,longitude: 10.035604, zoom: 1)


        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setValue(2.0, forKey: kCATransactionAnimationDuration)
        let city = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(58.998400,longitude: 10.035604, zoom: 15)
        self.mapView.animateToCameraPosition(city)
        CATransaction.commit()
```

Answer (score 2):

> **Update for swift 5**

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setValue(1.0, forKey: kCATransactionAnimationDuration)
let city = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget:  CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude, longitude:logitude), zoom: 16)
self.mapView.animate(to: city)
CATransaction.commit()
```

Comment: I tried @Amrit's answer and it didn't work but this one neither.