# GMSMapView is not zooming in

Tags: ios, google-maps, zooming, gmsmapview

I am loading a Google Place from the autocomplete API then looking up place details to zoom in on my map.

I have a `GMSMapView` defined in my XIB which I can see when I run my view controller.

Originally the zoom level is at 4.
When I set the coordinate and zoom level, it stays zoomed out despite my debugger saying the zoom level is 2.

How do I zoom in?

```
(lldb) po self.map
<GMSMapView: 0x7f8c62a9ebc0; frame = (0 73.3333; 414 576.667); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7f8c67029fc0>; layer = <GMSMapLayer: 0x7f8c62a57aa0>>

(lldb) po self.map.camera
GMSCameraPosition 0x7f8c62d2d030: target:(29.741, -95.374) bearing:0.000 zoomLevel:2.000 viewingAngle:0.000


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setupButtons];

    self.map.delegate = self;

    self.client = [GMSPlacesClient sharedClient];
    [self.client lookUpPlaceID:self.prediction.placeID callback:^(GMSPlace * _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        [self showResult:result];
    }];
}

- (void)showResult:(GMSPlace *)place {
    self.place = place;

GMSCameraPosition *position = [[GMSCameraPosition alloc] initWithTarget:place.coordinate zoom:0.2 bearing:0 viewingAngle:0];
    [self.map setCamera:position];
    [self.map animateWithCameraUpdate:[GMSCameraUpdate setTarget:place.coordinate zoom: 0.15]];   

    [self.map moveCamera:[GMSCameraUpdate setTarget:place.coordinate zoom: 0.15]];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried methods like `setCamera:` or `[self.map animateWithCameraUpdate:[GMSCameraUpdate setTarget:place.coordinate zoom: 0.15]];` ?

Comment: I have tried animateWithCameraUpdate and setCamera -- edited above^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are doing something wrong here. You said that

> Originally the zoom level is at 4. When I set the coordinate and zoom level, it stays zoomed out despite my debugger saying the zoom level is 2.

Just to be clear, zoom level 4 is > zoom level 2. If you want your map to be zoomed in try using higher values i.e. around 15, 16 etc.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [**zoom**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/views#zoom) programmatically with `animateToZoom:` on GMSMapView.

Sample codes are shown below:

**Objective-C**

`[mapView_ animateToZoom:12];`

**Swift**

`mapView.animateToZoom(12)`

Aside from that, you can also restrict the range of zoom available to the map by setting a min and max zoom level. The zoom range must be set using the `setMinZoom:maxZoom:` method, however the values can be read individually using the `minZoom` and `maxZoom` properties. This is helpful when restricting only one of the values.

You may find sample codes in the given documentation and you may also use [GMSMapView Class Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_map_view) for the other methods related to the map.

And, this SO post - [GMSMapView animateToCameraPosition zoom in - zoom out animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30898937/gmsmapview-animatetocameraposition-zoom-in-zoom-out-animation) might also help.